# link opencv with anaconda's python in ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 15.04 and I have installed anaconda2 in it. I have edited the ~/.profile 's PATH variable to anaconda's bin directory.I have also installed default version of conda's opencv using `conda install opencv`  , but the problem is it doesn't work for videocapture. I tried various solution like installing [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249611/videocapture-does-not-work-in-anaconda) and tried every possible solution on internet, nothing worked.

Previously when I didn't have anaconda I was able to do videocapture and other computer vision stuff through official opencv version from website and my default ubuntu python(`/usr/bin/python`) so I am planning to reinstall opencv from website and link it with anaconda's python, how can I do it?

P.S. I will be needing anaconda packages so can't remove it and I am using a 64 bit ubuntu 15.04.