# FFMPEG not installed when it is installed

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ffmpeg, ar.drone

As a follow up to my prior question, I was able to solve

`import cv2
import libardrone.libardrone`

I reinstalled opencv and I realized the documentation was incorrect; it was supposed to be

`import libardrone.ardrone`

Solving these two problems let me to be able to attempt the track.py given here: https://github.com/JJLewis/ColorTracking-ARDrone2.0-Python.

Running track.py gives me the follow errors even though I have ffmpeg installed correctly.

```
WARNING:root:Connection to ardrone

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/track.py", line 180, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/track.py", line 19, in main
    drone = libardrone.ARDrone(True, False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/ardrone.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.network_process = arnetwork.ARDroneNetworkProcess(com_pipe_other, is_ar_drone_2, self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/arnetwork.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.ar2video = ar2video.ARVideo2(self._drone, drone.debug)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/ar2video.py", line 37, in __init__
    h264 = h264decoder.H264Decoder(self, drone.image_shape)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/h264decoder.py", line 82, in __init__
    raise Exception("You need to install ffmpeg to be able to run ardrone")
Exception: You need to install ffmpeg to be able to run ardrone
>>> Exception in thread Thread-35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/arnetwork.py", line 86, in run
    video_socket, nav_socket, control_socket = _connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/arnetwork.py", line 75, in _connect
    control_socket.connect(('192.168.1.1', ARDRONE_CONTROL_PORT))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

As a beginner, I am having difficulties resolving these issues. My specifications are as follows Mac 10.12, Python 2.7.14, and OpenCV 3.3.0_3.

Comment: Are you using Anaconda? There is a long-standing bug that prevents ffmpeg from working properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249611/videocapture-does-not-work-in-anaconda

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am using Python & Homebrew.